# Craft CMS 2 - Exporting entity issue

Tags: plugin-development, php, craft2

I installed this https://github.com/boboldehampsink/export plugin but getting error during exporting entities regarding to "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable", I tried to debug and applied some condition but not working, you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be related to the version of PHP on your server being too new for the version of Craft you're using.

I'm sure you're aware, but Craft 2 is no longer supported; I'd recommend updating to 3 (ideally 4) as soon as possible. Craft 3 and 4 also support exporting from the control panel natively without plugins.

Comment: there are php 7.2. Could you please suggest which version should we use for making compatible for the this export plugin. 
Is it easy to move craft 2 to craft 3?

Comment: @NikDev, You might give php v5.6 a try if v7.2 still gives you trouble. As far as upgrading, I would recommend going here: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/upgrade.html. The ease of updating will have to do a lot with the complexity of the site.